# Does every differential equation have a Lagrangian?

Tags: physics, euler-lagrange-equation

Given some differential equation/s, is it always possible to construct a Lagrangian, which reproduces the equation/s after applying the Euler-Lagrange equation?

As a specific example, consider a complex function $E(t)$, where $t$ is real. Then the equation:
$$\dfrac{\partial^{2}E}{\partial t^{2}}+AE=BE^{2}E^{*}\ ,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants, has a simple Lagrangian if $A$ and $B$ are real, namely:
$$L=\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial E^{*}}{\partial t}-AEE^{*}+\dfrac{B}{2}E^{2}(E^{*})^{2}\ ,$$
where we consider $E$ and $E^{*}$ as separate generalized coordinates. But, if $A$ and $B$ are complex, then I can't seem to find a Lagrangian?

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[First exposition of non-Hamiltonian system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287961/10024)" and the questions linked therein.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the specifics of your question, you want 
$$\dfrac{\partial^{2}E}{\partial t^{2}}+AE-BE^{2}E^{*}=0\\
\dfrac{\partial^{2}E^*}{\partial t^{2}}+A^*E^*-B^*E^{*2}E=0
$$
to be the extremal conditions of the *same* action, even though they are the complex conjugates of each other.

That is, performing the trivial and irrelevant integration by parts with respect to *t*, you essentially want both equations to be 
$$
\frac{\delta L }{\delta E} =0 , \qquad \frac{\delta L }{\delta E^*} =0.
$$
But, in order for these two to be mutual complex conjugates, you need 
*L* to be real, so
$$L=\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial E^{*}}{\partial t}-AEE^{*}+\dfrac{B}{2}E^{2}(E^{*})^{2}\ ,$$
with real coefficients *A,B*.

The pair of equations you posit then can only be the E-L equations of a lagrangian if the coeffs *A,B* are real.